# require("nodegit") prevents script from exiting

Tags: node.js, require, nodegit

I'm having trouble using [nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org/) (v0.9.0). Any .js script that `require`s the package will hang forever and not exit. Example:

```
var nodegit = require('nodegit');

console.log("hello world");
```

Running this on the command line will result in the expected console output, but the script will never exit. I need to use ctrl-C to get control back from the script.

However, if I comment out the require statement:

```
// var nodegit = require('nodegit');

console.log("hello world");
```

Things work just fine.

I've encountered this behaviour on both Windows (7) and Linux (CentOS 7.1.1503). Both machines using v4.2.0 of node. I'm guessing that this is not a bug, and that I'm misusing the library somehow, but I don't understand what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/866).

To work around the problem, you can call process.exit() when you're sure there's no more pending I/O.

Comment: FYI, things that will prevent a node process from existing include a pending timer or interval (that has not had `.unref()` called on it) or a live server listening for incoming connections or an open socket.